# dc.js sort ordinal line chart by y axis/value

Tags: javascript, d3.js, charts, dc.js

I have a dc.js ordinal chart whose x-axis consists of things like 'Cosmetics' and the y-axis is the number of sales. I want to sort the chart by sales decreasing, however when I use `.ordering(function(d){return -d.value.ty})` the path of the line chart is still ordered by the x-axis.[image: Mangled Graph]

```
var departmentChart = dc.compositeChart('#mystore_department_chart'),
                ndx = crossfilter(response.data),
                dimension = ndx.dimension(function(d) {return d.name}),
                group = dimension.group().reduce(function(p, v) {
                    p.ty += v.tyvalue;
                    p.ly += v.lyvalue;
                    return p;
                }, function(p, v) {
                    p.ty -= v.tyvalue;
                    p.ly -= v.lyvalue;
                    return p;
                }, function() {
                    return {
                        ty: 0,
                        ly: 0
                    }
                });

            departmentChart
                .ordering(function(d){return -d.value.ty})
                //dimensions
                //.width(768)
                .height(250)
                .margins({top: 10, right: 50, bottom: 25, left: 50})
                //x-axis
                .x(d3.scale.ordinal())
                .xUnits(dc.units.ordinal)
                .xAxisLabel('Department')
                //left y-axis
                .yAxisLabel('Sales')
                .elasticY(true)
                .renderHorizontalGridLines(true)
                //composition
                .dimension(dimension)
                .group(group)
                .compose([
                    dc.barChart(departmentChart)
                        .centerBar(true)
                        .gap(5)
                        .dimension(dimension)
                        .group(group, 'This Year')
                        .valueAccessor(function(d) {return d.value.ty}),

                    dc.lineChart(departmentChart)
                        .renderArea(false)
                        .renderDataPoints(true)
                        .dimension(dimension)
                        .group(group, 'Last Year')
                        .valueAccessor(function(d) {return d.value.ly})
                ])
                .brushOn(false)
                render();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the hack I ended up doing. Be aware that it could have performance issues on large data sets as all() is faster than top(Infinity). For some reason I couldn't get [Gordon's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23774871/dc-js-sort-ordinal-line-chart-by-y-axis-value/23788922#23788922) to work, but in theory it should.

On my group I specified an order function

```
group.order(function(p) {
    return p.myfield;
});
```

Then because all() doesn't use the order function I overrode the default all function

```
group.all = function() {
    return group.top(Infinity);
}
```

And then on my chart I had to specify an order function

```
chart.ordering(function(d){
    return -d.value.myfield
}); // order by myfield descending
```

Comment: Oh wow, overriding group.all. That's clever. Thanks for sharing how you fixed it; it should help with the real fix. Please accept your own answer

Comment: works good but the performance degradation with larger datasets is catastrophic !  Any work arounds ?

Answer (score 1):

No doubt this is a bug.

As a workaround, you could sort the data yourself instead of using the ordering function, [as described in the FAQ](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/wiki/FAQ#filter-the-data-before-its-charted).

I filed a bug report: https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/issues/598

Comment: I can confirm that the original group was ordered by key and when I implement the workaround the group is ordered by value but the chart is still ordering by the x-axis/key. And if I use the chart ordering function the same error still occurs.

Comment: Did you supply the same "fake group" in all three places? This is frustrating. If you can create a fiddle it will help a lot.

Comment: Yea I did. Thanks for the help and see my answer below on how I fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

It does appear to be a bug. I too couldn't make it work as intended.
I implemented a workaround; I added an example in a Plunker, link is (also) in the dc.js issue at github.
It is based upon a recent snapshot of dc.js 2.0.0-dev.
(So for now I guess this could be considered an answer)

http://embed.plnkr.co/VItIQ4ZcW9abfzI13z64/