# DC.js original ordering of ordinal scale on lineChart

Tags: javascript, d3.js, dc.js

I've got data on an ordinal scale that I'd like to visualize using a line chart in DC.js. The data looks something like this:

```
var data = {points:[{x:"A", y:23}, {x:"C", y:50}, {x:"B", y:40}]}
```

This works just fine using standard DC.js:

```
var chart = dc.lineChart("#chart");
var ndx = crossfilter(data.points);

var ordinal_dimension = ndx.dimension(function (d) {
    return d.x;
})

var loan_dimension = ordinal_dimension.group().reduceSum(function (d) {
    return d.y;
});

chart
    .width(800)
    .height(600)
    d3.scale.ordinal()
    .xUnits(dc.units.ordinal)
    .interpolate('linear')
    .renderArea(true)
    .clipPadding(10)
    .dimension(ordinal_dimension)
    .group(loan_dimension)

chart.render();
```

But what happens is that the ordering on the x axis gets changed; instead of "A", "C", "B" it's now "A", "B", "C".

In order to reverse the ordering, I tried to do something like this:

```
var x_scale = $.map(data.points, function(values) {
  return [values.x];
});

var x = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .domain(x_scale)
```

But this completely messes up the chart. See the example here: https://jsfiddle.net/ms9j4x00/7/

Is there any way to preserve the ordering in DC.js?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, that's annoying all right. You would think that you could use [`.ordering`](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/blob/develop/web/docs/api-latest.md#dc.baseMixin+ordering) for this, but no dice, it's not called for stacked charts.

The best workaround I can think of is to postprocess `group.all()` to get the correct order, and *also* set the x scale domain as you're doing.

So here's a "fake group" constructor which produces a group ordered manually:

```
function sort_group(group, order) {
    return {
        all: function() {
            var g = group.all(), map = {};

            g.forEach(function(kv) {
                map[kv.key] = kv.value;
            });
            return order.map(function(k) {
                return {key: k, value: map[k]};
            });
        }
    };
};
```

Use it like this:

```
var sorted_group = sort_group(loan_dimension, order);
chart.group(sorted_group)
```

Here's a working fork of your fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/gordonwoodhull/sjjnx72f/11/

For the sake of link-gardening, here is a related question: [dc.js sort ordinal line chart by y axis/value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23774871/dc-js-sort-ordinal-line-chart-by-y-axis-value)

and issue: https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/issues/598

I think the workarounds suggested there use basically the same method, although the kind of ordering they need is different.

Answer (score 0):

**A non-fake group approach** :

It is not a clean one, but definitely simple. We can try tagging the dimensions with a number before grouping. This helps auto-sort and in the final graph, the numbers can be removed with the help of tick Format.

Below is my code snippet:

```
var data = {
points: [{
    x: "A",
    y: 23
}, {
    x: "C",
    y: 50
}, {
    x: "B",
    y: 40
}]
}
var i = 1
    //Append a number to the x dimension as 01,02,03 etc
data.points.forEach(function(d) {
    if (i < 10) i = '0' + i;
    d.x_new = i + '_' + d.x;
    i = +i + 1;
    console.log(d.x_new);
});
var chart = dc.lineChart("#chart");
var ndx = crossfilter(data.points);

var ordinal_dimension = ndx.dimension(function(d) {
    return d.x_new;
})

var loan_dimension = ordinal_dimension.group().reduceSum(function(d) {
    return d.y;
});

chart
    .width(800)
    .height(600)
    .x(d3.scale.ordinal())
    .xUnits(dc.units.ordinal)
    .interpolate('linear')
    .renderArea(true)
    .clipPadding(10)
    .dimension(ordinal_dimension)
    .group(loan_dimension)
    .xAxis().ticks(3).tickFormat(function(d) {
        return d.split("_")[1];
    });

chart.render();
```

You could check this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/say2sabarish/ms9j4x00/8/) should you need more information.